# Array concept on trying to get the no of lines in the file

Tags: java, arrays

I have below code which reads the input from a file using scanner class and sorts the input using comparable interface. This code works fine for a fixed array size but I want to count the no.of lines which are there in the file.

```
public class ReadItemData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Scanner aScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(
                "src//chapter11//Items.txt"));

     double avg = 0;
         double sum = 0;
      Item[] itemArray = new Item[5];

            while (aScanner.hasNext()) 
        {
                String code = aScanner.next();
                String sku = aScanner.next();
                double qty = aScanner.nextDouble();

            itemArray[count] = new Item(code, sku, qty);
            System.out.println(itemArray[i]);
        i++;

        }
    Arrays.sort(itemArray[i]);
        System.out.println();
          for (Item it : itemArray) 
        {
            System.out.println(it);

            sum += qty;
        }
    avg = sum / 5;
    if(qty <= (avg - 10))
     {
     System.out.println("Quantity is 10 less than the average quantity");
     }
    }
    }
    class Item implements Comparable {
    private int qty;
    private String sku,code;

    public Item(String code, String sku,int qty) {
        this.code = code;
        this.sku = sku;
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public String getCode() {
            return code;
    }
    public String getSku() {
        return sku;
    }
    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }


    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Item i = (Item) o;
        return (this.sku).compareTo(i.sku);
    }
}
```

I tried declaring a int variable count and passed it to the array but I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
int count = 0;
Item[] itemArray = new Item[count];
```

One more issue I am facing is I am calculating the sum inside the loop,but I am not getting the desired results

My input file

```
PAP ENT 82
WAR HOT 79
TIM JUT 92
BON BLA 76
BON MAG 45
```

The sum of the quantity goes to 374,but in my code it's calculated to 225 and I am unable to figure out where I am doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding these into a fixed array add them into a java [list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). Once you have filled the list up use listClass.size() to retrieve the size of the list.

Here's some implementation:

```
       List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
       while (aScanner.hasNext()) 
       {
            String code = aScanner.next();
            String sku = aScanner.next();
            double qty = aScanner.nextDouble();

        itemList.add(new Item(code, sku, qty));
        System.out.println(itemList.get(i));
    i++;

    }
```

Now use itemList.size() anywhere to retrieve how many entries. You are implementing arrays wrong btw. When you are getting the array out of bounds error is due to the fact that you are initializing the array with 0 positions.

Your sum is incorrect due to not getting the correct item value:

```
for (Item it : itemArray) 
    {
        System.out.println(it);
        //You must get the iterated item quantity (I assume you don't have setters and                                     
        //getters
         sum += it.qty;
    }
```

Comment: I don't have a choice other than to use Arrays. Can I know what's the mistake I am making while initializing the array?

Comment: What do you mean you don't have a choice?  This is what the `ArrayList` class is for.

Comment: Oh, right.  A well-meaning professor telling their students that they have to solve the problem the WRONG way.  Yay!

Comment: Yup,it's an assignment

Comment: @Sandy If you don't have a choice you will have to dynamically create an array and copy it over or make one bigger than you think the amount of entries will ever be. Also make a counter in the aScanner.next() (You already have one in i++ )loop and that will tell you how many items are in that array.

Comment: The max possible items would be 100. So you mean that I need to do this way    int count = 100;
Item[] itemArray = new Item[count]; Yes in the loop I am incrementing the counter. But I don't think above syntax is correct. Is it?

Comment: @Sandy Yes it's correct. It's not the most efficient way (to have arrays at max possible objects) but it should work for this case. Now make sure i is 0 at initialization and your i variable will be how many items are in that array.

Comment: Well, I am trying to figure out where I am going wrong. int i = 0,count=100; while(ascanner.hasNext){....;i++;count++;} error at line 40(itemArray[count] = new Item(code, sku, qty);) ArrayIndexOutOfBound

Comment: @Sandy You want itemArray[i] = new Item(code,sku,qty);

Comment: @Sandy If you had `itemArray[count] = new Item(code,sku,qty)` it would just override `itemArray[100]` entry for each object you have in your text. You should read up on array's before you go any further...

Comment: It gives me Nullpointer exception while sorting now..NullPointerException at Line 49(Arrays.sort(itArray);)...I kept as int i=0,count=100 and inside the loop itemArray[i] = new Item(code,sku,qty); count++;i++

Comment: @Sandy that's because your sort is incorrect. Also once your out of that loop `i` increments again and `Arrays.sort(itemArray[i])` is indeed pointing to a null position in the array. Again, please go read up on arrays.

Comment: I am sorting the whole array  rather than at a particular position. Arrays.sort(itemArray); The sort functionality is working fine. The only thing I am messing up is finding the no of lines in the file and passing it as the size of array